# automate program tasks silently

Tags: windows, software-rec

I wanna control a program and record all my steps then do it silently with a script

- tried AutoIT but some steps couldn't deal with it see this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3acay.png)
  here I can't click on install the only way with mouse click but the resolution difference stopping me cuz it will run on a lot of devices.
- I like Silent Install Builder...It can make a gui script just click ctrl and click on any button on the setup file and it will record everything and do it silently next time
- I wanna make the same but for Protable Programs not Setups

Comment: You want ControlClick(), not MouseClick() https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/183334-click-a-button-through-title-class-instance/

Comment: @Gantendo I clicked on that link...He have the same problem but nothing in comments !

Comment: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlClick.htm

Comment: @Gantendo Did you see my screen shot ? I can't get button info no id nothing at all...So ControlClick can't be used (:

Comment: I can't see the crosshair in that screenshot. Anyway, you could try starting the program and pressing Tab a bunch of times until the correct button has focus and then pressing spacebar to push it